# mysql workbench exporting sql files instead of sql text file

Tags: export, mysql-workbench

I watch youtube tutorials how to export a database and i noticed that, when i export my database

it a `".sql"` file instead of `SQL text file.`

```
Are those thing are the same?
```

**if not what can i do to make a sql text file?**

this  are the steps of how import it

[image]

*then i click start export*

did i do it wrong?

the tutorial that i watched looks like this:

[image]

but mine looks like this:

[image]

i used sqlworkbench 8.0

Comment: .SQL dump is common text file with "SQL" extension.

Comment: so it doesn't change anything when i-import it to another scehema?

Comment: Don't watch videos, read the help. And do it strictly as it is written in the help.